# Pandas: How to fill missing period/datetime values in a multiindex time series?

Tags: pandas, time-series, missing-data

I have a multiindex dataframe where one of the indexes is a Period or DateTime. It has some missing values like the one below:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame(zip(['x']*4+['y']*4, 
                      range(8), 
                      list(pd.period_range('2020-08-02T00:00:00', '2020-08-02T03:00:00', freq='H'))*2)
                  ,columns=['a', 'b', 'd']).set_index(['a', 'd'])
dt = dt.drop([('x',pd.Period('2020-08-02 01:00', 'H')), 
              ('y',pd.Period('2020-08-02 01:00', 'H'))])
dt
```

[image: mult-iindex dataframe with missing values]

I'd like to fill the missing period values with NaN. The end result would be:

[image: desired result]

If I had a time series with a simple index, it would be easy: `dt.resample('H').first()`. How should I do it in this multi-index timeseries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment under Henry Yik, I assume that all time series are within the same range, so I guess you can use `reindex` and create the `MultiIndex.from_product` like:

```
dt_ = dt.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                    [dt.index.get_level_values('a').unique(), 
                     pd.date_range(dt.index.get_level_values('d').min(), 
                                   dt.index.get_level_values('d').max(), 
                                   freq='H')], 
                     names=dt.index.names))
print(dt_)
                         b
a d                       
x 2020-08-02 00:00:00  0.0
  2020-08-02 01:00:00  NaN
  2020-08-02 02:00:00  2.0
  2020-08-02 03:00:00  3.0
y 2020-08-02 00:00:00  4.0
  2020-08-02 01:00:00  NaN
  2020-08-02 02:00:00  6.0
  2020-08-02 03:00:00  7.0
```

Comment: didn't know about the `MultiIndex.from_product`. I was already doing it manually.

Comment: change the `pd.date_range` to `pd.period_range` to make it perfect

Comment: @neves yes right you used `period_range` in your question, I'm not familiar with this Period class, but works the same way with the above creation of MultiIndex :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could simply reset the index for a `groupby`:

```
dt = dt.reset_index("a").groupby("a").resample('H').first()

dt["a"] = dt["a"].ffill()

print (dt)

                    a    b
a d                       
x 2020-08-02 00:00  x  0.0
  2020-08-02 01:00  x  NaN
  2020-08-02 02:00  x  2.0
  2020-08-02 03:00  x  3.0
y 2020-08-02 00:00  y  4.0
  2020-08-02 01:00  y  NaN
  2020-08-02 02:00  y  6.0
  2020-08-02 03:00  y  7.0
```

Comment: Right you are. Or OP can simply `set_index` to column "d" only in the first place :)

Comment: Nice! It won't generate a NaN value is the missing period is at the end or beginning of the periods.