# Fill up missing dates (with default values) in a data frame date column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, validation

What uniquely identifies a record in my data frame is the combination **[location, date]**. As I am doing some window/rolling calculations over time, I need to make sure that there's a full set of dates for each location for each year/month/date. I have some issues with my data which is missing dates as can be seen here:

[image]

As you can see, there's no values for 25th and 26th of Dec, 2017. What needs to go there is:

```
9708 | 2017-12-25 | 0
9708 | 2017-12-26 | 0
```

is this possible somehow? I have tried re-indexing as describe [here](https://www.skytowner.com/explore/adding_missing_dates_in_datetime_index_in_pandas_dataframe) but the problem is that I have an additional column: **location**

Comment: kindly provide reproducible sample dataframe, with expected output - you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63271274/7175713) and see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .groupby() to group based on location and date (month based) and generate a dataframe with all possible days for each location-month combination. Merge with the values you already have. Finally fill missing values with 0

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def fill_month(group):
    year = group.date.dt.year.unique()[0]
    month = group.date.dt.month.unique()[0]
    num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=f"{year}-{month}-01", end=f"{year}-{month}-{num_days}", freq='D')
    df_dates = pd.DataFrame({"location":[group.location.unique()[0] for i in range(len(date_range))],"date":date_range})
    df_tmp = pd.merge(df_dates, group, on=['location', 'date'], how='left').fillna(0)
    return df_tmp

df = df.groupby([df['location'], df['date'].dt.to_period('M')],group_keys=False).apply(fill_month)
```